# mysqldbcopy exclude regex pattern

Tags: mysql, regex, copy, regex-negation

I want to copy a database using mysqldbcopy. Some tables (e.g. tbl1) should be copied without her data, and some others (e.g. tbl2) should be full copied with all of the content. So i would like to copy first all tables with content and exclude the tables which i want to copy without the content like this:

```
mysqldbcopy --exclude=mydb.tbl1 --source=[...]
```

After that I want to copy the tables without content by adding --skip=data to the parameters. Because it seems not possible to tell mysqldbcopy which tables he should copy, my idea was to negate --exclude by using a regex-pattern:

```
mysqldbcopy --exclude=mydb\.[^tbl1]+ --regexp --skip=data --source=[...]
```

This should copy the structure of all tables expect those which data (in this case tbl2). But --exclude seems not to work with any pattern. For testing i tried

```
mysqldbcopy --exclude=mydb\.[tbl1]+ --regexp --skip-data --source=[...]
```

But the exclude-parameter was ignored, he copied all the tables. I tried to use \ instead of \ for escaping the dot between database-name and table for the regex, but this make no difference. 
Sadly using regex-pattern with mysqldbcopy seems not very good documentated, the manual only tells me

> -x EXCLUDE, --exclude=EXCLUDE
>   exclude one or more objects from the operation using either a specific name (e.g. db1.t1), a LIKE pattern (e.g. db1.t% or db%.%) or a REGEXP search pattern. To use a REGEXP search pattern for all exclusions, you must also specify the --regexp option.

I cloudn't find any examples how to use regex here.